# I do not know if I am initializing ADC correctly for PIC24F

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, adc

I am using a Microchip Pic24f board to receive 3 analog inputs from a accelerometer.

I am getting a signal for AN0 but for AN1 and AN2 there is a signal but the values are not right.

Here is the code where I initialize ADC.

```
void InitADC(int amask) {
  AD1PCFG = 0xFFF8; // select AN0, AN1, AN2 as analog input
  AD1CON1 = 0x00E0; // auto convert @ end of sampling, Integer Data in.

  AD1CON2 = 0x0000; // use MUXA, AVss and AVdd used as Vref

  AD1CON3 = 0x1F01; // Tad = 2xTcy = 125ns. 31*Tad for conversion time.
  AD1CSSL = 0; // no scanning required
  AD1CHS=0;
  AD1CHS=1;
  AD1CHS=2;

  AD1CON1bits.ADON = 1; // Turn on the ADC
} // InitADC
```

In the main():

```
TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 1;
TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 1;
TRISBbits.TRISB2 = 1;
```

I then read AD1PCFG = 0xFFFE; for each analog input in a different function.

The results of the inputs are read in by in that same function

```
return ADC1BUF0;
```

I am not sure if for the PIC24f if I need to use ADC1BUFx for each ANx analog input or if I can read the signals through just ADC1BUF0.

Also I do not know if I need to scan and for AD1CON2 the configuration needs to be different because of the multiple analog inputs being used.

I am fairly new to PIC24f and have searched everywhere for help and everything that I was able to try got me to get the signals to be read on the LCD but AN1 and AN2 data is not what it is supposed to be.

If anyone could help me that it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that show how I implemented what is found in the Microchip family reference manual describing the type of ADC you may be using:

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC24FJ64GA002
 * IDE: MPLABX v5.45
 * Compiler: XC16 v1.61
 *  
 * Description:
 * 
 *  Initialize the ADC to convert voltage levels present on AN0, AN1 and AN5
 *  
 *  Map UART1 with TXD on RB0 and RXD on RB1.
 *  Map UART2 with TXD on RB8 and RXD on RB8.
 * 
 *  Initialize UART2 at 9600 baud and hook to printf.
 *
 * Created on March 11, 2021, 1:46 PM
 * 
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552251/i-do-not-know-if-i-am-initializing-adc-correctly-for-pic24f
 *
 *                            PIC24FJ64GA002
 *               +-----------------:_:-----------------+
 *   ICD_VPP -> :  1 MCLR                     VDD  28 : <- 3v3
 *           <> :  2 RA0/RP26/AN0             VSS  27 : <- GND
 *           <> :  3 RA1/RP27/AN1   AN9 /RP15/RB15 26 : <> LED4
 *   ICD_PGD <> :  4 RB0/PGD1/AN2   AN10/RP14/RB14 25 : <> LED5
 *   ICD_PGC <> :  5 RB1/PGC1/AN3   AN11/RP13/RB13 24 : <> LED6
 *           <> :  6 RB2/RP2/AN4    AN12/RP12/RB12 23 : <> LED7
 *       POT <> :  7 RB3/RP3/AN5         RP11/RB11 22 : <>
 *       GND -> :  8 VSS                 RP10/RB10 21 : <>
 * 7.3728MHz <> :  9 RA2/OSCI                 VCAP 20 : <- 10uF
 * 7.3728MHz <> : 10 RA3/OSCO                 VSS  19 : <- GND
 *           <> : 11 RB4/SOSC            RP9 /RB9  18 : <> RXD
 *           <> : 12 RA4/SOSC            RP8 /RB8  17 : <> TXD
 *       3v3 -> : 13 VDD           INT0/ RP7 /RB7  16 : <>
 *       SW1 <> : 14 RB5/RP5             RP6 /RB6  15 : <>
 *               +-------------------------------------+
 *                               DIP-28
 *
 */

// CONFIG2
#pragma config POSCMOD = NONE           // Primary Oscillator Select (Primary oscillator disabled)
#pragma config I2C1SEL = PRI            // I2C1 Pin Location Select (Use default SCL1/SDA1 pins)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // IOLOCK Protection (IOLOCK may be changed via unlocking seq)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = ON            // Primary Oscillator Output Function (OSC2/CLKO/RC15 functions as port I/O (RC15))
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor (Clock switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor are disabled)
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCPLL           // Oscillator Select (Fast RC Oscillator with PLL module (FRCPLL))
#pragma config SOSCSEL = SOSC           // Sec Oscillator Select (Default Secondary Oscillator (SOSC))
#pragma config WUTSEL = LEG             // Wake-up timer Select (Legacy Wake-up Timer)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Internal External Switch Over Mode (IESO mode (Two-Speed Start-up) enabled)

// CONFIG1
#pragma config WDTPS = PS32768          // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:32,768)
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128            // WDT Prescaler (Prescaler ratio of 1:128)
#pragma config WINDIS = ON              // Watchdog Timer Window (Standard Watchdog Timer enabled,(Windowed-mode is disabled))
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable (Watchdog Timer is disabled)
#pragma config ICS = PGx1               // Comm Channel Select (Emulator EMUC1/EMUD1 pins are shared with PGC1/PGD1)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Code Segment Write Protect (Writes to program memory are allowed)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Code Segment Code Protect (Code protection is disabled)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Port Enable (JTAG port is disabled)

#define FCY (16000000ul)                // This define allows the delay macros to work

#include "xc.h"
#include <libpic30.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* define map input pin numbers */
enum
{   
    RPI0  = 0,      /* pin RB00 */ /* PGC1 */
    RPI1,           /* pin RB01 */ /* PGD1 */
    RPI2,           /* pin RB02 */
    RPI3,           /* pin RB03 */
    RPI4,           /* pin RB04 */
    RPI5,           /* pin RB05 */
    RPI6,           /* pin RB06 */
    RPI7,           /* pin RB07 */
    RPI8,           /* pin RB08 */
    RPI9,           /* pin RB09 */
    RPI10,          /* pin RB10 */
    RPI11,          /* pin RB11 */
    RPI12,          /* pin RB12 */
    RPI13,          /* pin RB13 */
    RPI14,          /* pin RB14 */
    RPI15,          /* pin RB15 */
    RPI_NONE = 0x1f  
};  
    
/* define map output function numbers */
enum
{   
    RPO_NONE = 0,
    RPO_C1OUT,      
    RPO_C2OUT,      
    RPO_U1TX,       
    RPO_U1RTS,      
    RPO_U2TX,       
    RPO_U2RTS,      
    RPO_SDO1,       
    RPO_SCK1OUT,    
    RPO_SS1OUT,     
    RPO_SDO2,       
    RPO_SCK2OUT,    
    RPO_SS2OUT,     
    RPO_OC1=18,        
    RPO_OC2,        
    RPO_OC3,        
    RPO_OC4,        
    RPO_OC5,        
};  
    
/* Initialize this PIC */
void
PIC_Init(
    void
    )
{   
    /* 
    ** Disable all interrupt sources
    */ 
    __builtin_disi(0x3FFF); /* disable interrupts for 16383 cycles */
    IEC0 = 0;
    IEC1 = 0;
    IEC2 = 0;
    IEC3 = 0;
    IEC4 = 0;
    __builtin_disi(0x0000); /* enable interrupts */

    CLKDIV =  0x0000; /* set for default clock operations */
    AD1PCFG = 0xffff; /* Set for digital I/O */
#ifdef AD1PCFGH
    AD1PCFGH = 0xffff;
#endif
    CMCON   = 0x0000;

    _NSTDIS = 1;    /* disable interrupt nesting */
    
    TRISA   = 0xFFFF;
    TRISB   = 0xFFFF;
    
    /* Unlock Registers */
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & ~_OSCCON_IOLOCK_MASK);
    
    /* map inputs */
    
    _INT1R  = RPI_NONE; /* External Interrupt 1    */
    _INT2R  = RPI_NONE; /* External Interrupt 2    */
    _T2CKR  = RPI_NONE; /* Timer2 External Clock   */
    _T3CKR  = RPI_NONE; /* Timer3 External Clock   */
    _T4CKR  = RPI_NONE; /* Timer4 External Clock   */
    _T5CKR  = RPI_NONE; /* Timer5 External Clock   */
    _IC1R   = RPI_NONE; /* Input Capture 1         */
    _IC2R   = RPI_NONE; /* Input Capture 2         */
    _IC3R   = RPI_NONE; /* Input Capture 3         */
    _IC4R   = RPI_NONE; /* Input Capture 4         */
    _IC5R   = RPI_NONE; /* Input Capture 5         */
    _OCFAR  = RPI_NONE; /* Output Compare Fault A  */
    _OCFBR  = RPI_NONE; /* Output Compare Fault B  */
    _U1RXR  = RPI1;     /* UART1 Receive           */
    _U1CTSR = RPI_NONE; /* UART1 Clear To Send     */
    _U2RXR  = RPI9;     /* UART2 Receive           */
    _U2CTSR = RPI_NONE; /* UART2 Clear To Send     */
    _SDI1R  = RPI_NONE; /* SPI1 Data Input         */
    _SCK1R  = RPI_NONE; /* SPI1 Clock Input        */
    _SS1R   = RPI_NONE; /* SPI1 Slave Select Input */
    _SDI2R  = RPI_NONE; /* SPI2 Data Input         */
    _SCK2R  = RPI_NONE; /* SPI2 Clock Input        */
    _SS2R   = RPI_NONE; /* SPI2 Slave Select Input */
    
    /* map outputs */
    _RP0R   = RPO_U1TX;  /* U1 TXD */               /* pin RB00 */ /* PGC1 */
    _RP1R   = RPO_NONE;  /* U1 RXD */               /* pin RB01 */ /* PGD1 */
    _RP2R   = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB02 */
    _RP3R   = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB03 */
    _RP4R   = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB04 */
    _RP5R   = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB05 */
    _RP6R   = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB06 */
    _RP7R   = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB07 */
    _RP8R   = RPO_U2TX; /* U2 TXD */                /* pin RB08 */
    _RP9R   = RPO_NONE; /* U2 RXD */                /* pin RB09 */
    _RP10R  = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB10 */
    _RP11R  = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB11 */
    _RP12R  = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB12 */
    _RP13R  = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB13 */
    _RP14R  = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB14 */
    _RP15R  = RPO_NONE;                             /* pin RB15 */
    
    /* Lock Registers */
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | _OSCCON_IOLOCK_MASK);
}
/*
 * Initialize the ADC
 */
static const uint8_t Selector[] = {0x00,0x01,0x05};

void ADC_Init(void)
{
    AD1PCFGbits.PCFG0 = 0;  /* AN0/RA0 */
    AD1PCFGbits.PCFG1 = 0;  /* AN1/RA1 */
    AD1PCFGbits.PCFG5 = 0;  /* AN5/RB3 */

    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1;
    TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 1;
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 1;
    
    AD1CON1 = 0x0000;       // SAMP bit = 0 ends sampling and starts converting
    AD1CHS  = 0x0000;       // default to channel 0       
    AD1CSSL = 0;
    AD1CON3 = 0x0102;       // Manual Sample, TAD = 3 TCY, Auto-Sample Time 1 TAD
    AD1CON2 = 0;
    AD1CON1bits.ADON = 1;   // turn ADC ON

}
/*
 * ADC Read channel
 */
uint16_t ADC_ReadChannel(uint16_t Index)
{
    if(Index < sizeof(Selector))
    {
        AD1CHSbits.CH0SA = Selector[Index];
    }
    AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 1;   // start sampling...
    __delay_us(5);          // Ensure the correct sampling time has elapsed before starting conversion.
    AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 0;   // start converting
    for(;;)
    {
        if(AD1CON1bits.DONE) break; // conversion done?
    }
    
    return ADC1BUF0;  // yes then get ADC value
}
/*
 * Initialize UART2
 */
#define U2_BAUD 9600L
#define U2_BRGH_VALUE 0

#if U2_BRGH_VALUE
#define U2_BRGH_SCALE 4L
#else
#define U2_BRGH_SCALE 16L
#endif

#define U2_BRGREG (FCY/(U2_BRGH_SCALE * U2_BAUD)-1L)

#if U2_BRGREG > 65535
#error Cannot set up UART2 for the FCY and BAUDRATE. Correct values in init.h and uart.h files.
#endif

/*
** Check if baud error greater than 2.5 percent
*/
#define REAL_BAUDRATE ( FCY / ( U2_BRGH_SCALE * ( U2_BRGREG + 1L) ) )

#if (REAL_BAUDRATE > (U2_BAUD + (U2_BAUD * 25L) / 1000L)) || (REAL_BAUDRATE < (U2_BAUD - (U2_BAUD * 25L) / 1000L))
#error UART baudrate error greater than 2.5 percent for the FCY and U2_BAUD. Correct values in uart.c file.
#endif
#undef REAL_BAUDRATE

void UART2_Init(void)
{
    _U2TXIE = 0;
    _U2RXIE = 0;
    _U2ERIE = 0;
    _U2RXIP = 0b100;
    _U2TXIP = 0b100;
    _U2ERIP = 0b100;

    U2MODE = 0;
    U2STA = 0;

    U2BRG = U2_BRGREG;
    U2MODEbits.BRGH = U2_BRGH_VALUE;
    U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;
    U2STAbits.UTXEN  = 1;
}
void UART2_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(U2STAbits.TRMT != 1);

    U2TXREG = txData;    // Write the data byte to the USART.
}
/*
 * hook for printf
 */
int __attribute__((__section__(".libc.write"))) write(int handle, void *buffer, unsigned int len) 
{
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = len; i; --i)
    {
        UART2_Write(*(char*)buffer++);
    }
    return(len);
}
/*
 * Main Application
 */
int main(void) 
{
    uint16_t ADC_results[sizeof(Selector)];
    uint16_t ADC_value;
    uint16_t NewResults;
    uint16_t Index;
    
    PIC_Init();
    ADC_Init();
    UART2_Init();
    
    printf("\r\nPIC24FJ64GA002 start, built on %s at %s\r\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
    /*
     * Application loop
     */
    NewResults = 1;
    for(;;)
    {
        for(Index = 0; Index < sizeof(Selector); Index++)
        {
            ADC_value = ADC_ReadChannel(Index);
            if (ADC_value != ADC_results[Index])
            {
                NewResults |= 1;
            }
            ADC_results[Index] = ADC_value;
        }
        if(NewResults)
        {
            NewResults = 0;
            printf("Values");
            for(Index = 0; Index < (sizeof(ADC_results)/sizeof(*ADC_results) ); Index++)
            {
                printf(" AN%1u = %5u", Selector[Index], ADC_results[Index]);
            }
            printf("\r\n");
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You do not provide enough information in your post to know which one of the 55 controllers you may actually be using.

I used the PIC24FJ64GA002 controller that I can find right now that has the ADC hardware you could be using.